# Java - Getting an OutOfMemoryError while parsing a ZipInputStream

Tags: java, json, zip, out-of-memory, zipinputstream

I have a problem reading the content of a zip file retrieved from a webservice.

The zip file is stored in a byte array called `bytes` as you can see in the code below.

```
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes.get()));
String rawJson = IOUtils.toString(zis);
```

When I execute `IOUtils.toString(zis)` I get an **OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**.

I'm shure that the problem is caused by the dimension of the json file contained in the zip, is bigger than 150MB. I've tried with other smaller files and I can get the json content without any problem.

Is there a way to read the content of the zip without storing it in memory?

**EDIT:**
I know that I could increase my heap memory but I'm looking for a code-based solution because it woud work on any environment.

Answer (score 0):

If u are using IDE, then try to do this

```
Run Configuration > Arguments > -Xmx7048m
```

increase the maximum ram to compile

Comment: This could be a solution but my code could run on environments I couldn't controll so I'm looking for a more general, and code based, solution.
Thank you by the way ;-)